# Is there a way to kill processes that are created by exec > >( process ) for I/o redirection

Tags: bash, subprocess, io-redirection

I'm redirecting stdout and stderr to bash subprocesses using exec in the following way:

```
exec 6>&1 7>&2      # Save file descriptors 1 and 2.
exec 2> >( while read LINE; do logger -p local2.err -t systemimager "$0: $LINE"; done )
exec > >( while read LINE; do logger -p local2.info -t systemimager "$0: $LINE"; done )

# Some bash commands

# Restore file descriptors
exec 1>&6 6>&- 2>&7 7>&-
```

Does restoring the file descriptors send a signup to the subshells?

Or is there any way to tell to those sub process that they are not needed anymore?

I'd like to avoid having useless dead subshells.

Multiple similar scripts are run as dracut hook in an initrd. I need to log the stdout and stderr of all hooks to journald. (centos7)

Aside that, I have a log dispatcher service that process journald and display all lines on my Plymouth console and on my systemimager logging facility.

The aim is to have in correct order the bash command outputs (stdout and stderr) and systems logs like kernel messages and such.

For example, when a parted command is run, I can have in correct order, the parted stdout and stderr and kernel messages listing new partition.

More info here: https://github.com/finley/SystemImager/wiki

Comment: Once you close the file descriptor the `read` in your `while` loop condition will return false, and so exit the loop.

Comment: Cool, so when I restore the file descriptors 1 and 2, this is similar to close them (read returns fall) and reopen in their initial state?